# Does this wall look sound?

Tags: garage, masonry, storage

I want to hang pegboard and some French cleats on my garage walls, which have some cracks in the masonry. Are these likely to be cosmetic or structural defects? Assuming I hang everything from the studs, can I safely mount stuff on these walls?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Linear cracks in masonry do not necessarily indicate that the wall is unsound. Go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hang everything from the studs, you'll be OK. What type of wall is it? You mention masonry but with studs, plywood with stucco, block with studs and drywall? The cracks appear to be more cosmetic than structural failure.

Comment: Plaster, I think.